# Shower curb leaking from exterior corners

Tags: bathroom, shower, leak

I initially thought the water I was seeing outside the shower was from the shower door, but after running it and watching, it’s definitely leaking from the grout in both corners. Looking closer there is a visible crack in the grout in one corner and it feels soft and like I could pull a small chunk of grout out from the other corner. I know next to nothing about tiling or plumbing, but am seeing suggestions in Google results ranging from simply adding silicone around the base to ripping the entire shower out because the waterproofing may be damaged or pulling the drain to clear weep holes or re-grouting and sealing the entire shower. With so many approaches, I think my question is where to even start to determine the level of response needed in this situation?

I’ve had the house for about two and a half years and have done nothing to the grout aside from normal cleaning. The previous owners did a DIY install of the shower in 2017 or 2018.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkT4i.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkT4i.jpg)

[image]

Comment: What does the sealant between the tile and the interior side of the shower door look like? What does the sealant between the shower base and the interior side of the shower door look like?

Answer (score 0):

That's an acrylic base so your problem is greatly simplified and the leak is coming from your wall tile grout or the join between the wall tile and the acrylic base flange.

I'd start with redoing the silicon as that is the most likely and the easiest.

If any grout is cracking or loose you should remove and apply new grout.

I wouldn't worry too much about the wall waterproofing.  Generally it being a vertical surface is going to prevent major problems.